# MySQL stored procedure getting full data from table for the specific user id

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

On fetching cursor crnt_user_skills getting all data from table instead of getting data for the specific userid. I even tried by giving the specific userid manually but got all data from table instead of given userid. What's wrong with my code? Please help?
Actually more than one cursors are appearing inside cursor user_data, I only given one cursor inside user_data cursor. Variable declarations are actually for all cursors don't panic about that.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test2(IN latd FLOAT(10,6),IN lngtd FLOAT(10,6),IN user_ind INT,IN userid INT,user_exprts INT,user_intn INT,regdate TIMESTAMP)
COMMENT 'To list users within 150 miles range'
BEGIN
    DECLARE user_cnt_hndlr,ind_cnt_hndlr,exprts_cnt_hndlr,crnt_events_cnt_hndlr,mchd_uid,mchd_ind,mchd_clustered_industry_id,mchd_exprts,mchd_clustered_expertise_id,mchd_intn,weight_score,prev_ind_score,prev_exprts_score,user_event_id,user_skl_id,user_strngth,skl_cnt,user_skills_cnt_hndlr INT;
    DECLARE mchd_miles VARCHARACTER(50);
    DECLARE user_bosi_result CHAR(2);
    DECLARE mchd_regdate TIMESTAMP;
    DECLARE user_data CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT ((ACOS(SIN(latd * PI() / 180) * SIN(users.lat * PI() / 180) + COS(latd * PI() / 180) * COS(users.lat * PI() / 180) * COS((lngtd - users.lang) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance`,`users`.`id` AS `userid`, `users`.`industry`, `users`.`user_expertise`, `users`.`user_intention`, `users`.`reg_date`
        FROM `users`
        WHERE user_status = 'A'
        AND id <> userid
        HAVING distance <=250;
    DECLARE crnt_user_skills CURSOR FOR
        SELECT skillid,strength FROM user_skills WHERE userid = userid ORDER BY skillid ASC;
    SET weight_score = 0;
    user_data_section : BEGIN
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
            SET user_cnt_hndlr = 1;
        OPEN user_data;
            user_cursor_loop: LOOP
                FETCH user_data INTO mchd_miles,mchd_uid,mchd_ind,mchd_exprts,mchd_intn,mchd_regdate;
                IF user_cnt_hndlr = 1 THEN
                    LEAVE user_cursor_loop;
                END IF;
                skill_section : BEGIN
                    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
                        SET user_skills_cnt_hndlr = 1;
                    SET skl_cnt = 0;
                    OPEN crnt_user_skills;
                        usr_skl_loop : LOOP
                            FETCH crnt_user_skills INTO user_skl_id,user_strngth;
                            IF user_skills_cnt_hndlr = 1 THEN
                                LEAVE usr_skl_loop;
                            END IF;
                            SET skl_cnt = getSkillsCount(skl_cnt,user_skl_id,user_strngth,mchd_uid);
                            INSERT INTO recmd_cnds_test(usr_ind1,matchd_ind1,industry_id1,clustered_industry_id1,bosi) VALUES(userid,user_skl_id,user_strngth,mchd_uid,'SI');
                        END LOOP usr_skl_loop;
                    CLOSE crnt_user_skills;
                    SET user_skills_cnt_hndlr = 0;
                    SET weight_score = calculateSkillsWeightScore(weight_score,skl_cnt);
                END skill_section;
                INSERT INTO `recmd_cnds` (`user_id` ,`recmd_id` ,`wgt_score`)VALUES (userid, mchd_uid, weight_score);
            END LOOP user_cursor_loop;
        CLOSE user_data;
        SET user_cnt_hndlr = 0;
    END user_data_section;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

I got, the answer, in the query `SELECT skillid,strength FROM user_skills WHERE userid = userid ORDER BY skillid ASC;` variable declaration userid and field name userid should not be same. As in the query `userid = userid` even though field name has a quot.